# How to avoid race condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, race-condition

I've got a potential race condition in an application I'm developing, which I'd like to account for and avoid in my querying.

To summarise the application flow...

1. Create a new row in the `entries` table:

   `INSERT INTO entries ( name, email ) VALUES ( 'Foo Bar', 'foo@example.com' );`
2. Find out if Mr Bar is a winner by checking a time-sensitive `prizes` table:

   `SELECT id FROM prizes WHERE various_time_conditions = 'met' AND id NOT IN ( SELECT prize_id FROM entries );`
3. If he's a winner, update his entry row accordingly:

   `UPDATE entries SET prize_id = [prize id] WHERE id = [entry id];`

As each prize can only be given out once, I need to eliminate any possibility of a race condition where another process can query the prizes table and update the entry table between steps 2 and 3 above.

I've been doing some research and have found a load of information about transactions (all my tables use InnoDB) and using MySQL's `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` syntax but I'm confused as to which is the most suitable solution for me.

Comment: Put all queries in a transaction for a quick insurance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to want to lock the prize record. So add some availability flag on the prizes table (perhaps with a default value) if you're not going to use something like a winner_id. Something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM prizes WHERE ... AND available = 1 FOR UPDATE
```

Then set the availability if you do assign the prize:

```
UPDATE prizes SET available = 0 WHERE id = ...
```

You'll need to wrap this inside a transaction of course.

Make sure that **every time** you check to see if the prize is available, you add `AND available = 1 FOR UPDATE` to the query because a `SELECT` without the `FOR UPDATE` is not going to wait for a lock.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds reasonable to me. Am I right in assuming that running the `UPDATE` statement will automatically release the lock granted by the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` query?

Comment: @SamHastings, committing or rolling back the transaction releases the lock. Performing the `UPDATE` doesn't release the lock because you may wish to perform multiple updates.